# DbQuery.Include() method: Is there a strong-typed variant?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, strong-typing

This is EF6. I can include `.Include()` method (no puns intended) in my queries to eager-load information from related tables. However it looks like .Include() method accepts a string parameter only. Is there a way to do it in a strongly-typed way? So for example, instead of writing `MyContext.catalog_item.Include("picture")`, I could write something like `MyDB.catalog_item.Include(i => i.picture)` to gain advantages like intellisense and all that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yep, there is a strongly typed variant in [System.Data.Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Usage is

```
.Include(i => i.Property)
```

The reference page gives examples on how to include collections and properties on collections as well.

Example:

```
query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference)).
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `IQueryable` extention method added in EF 5:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

You may want to have a look at how to perform includes of nested navigation properties